# Bounded convex function on a non-compact set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, compactness

Let $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb R$ where $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an unbounded (but closed) convex set. If $f$ is bounded and convex, can we say anything about the extremum of it?

For $n=1$ and $A=\mathbb{R}$ the only case these assumptions can hold is for a constant function $f$. Can we say the same thing for $n>1$? If not, is there a simple example of such a bounded function on an unbounded convex set?

Comment: There are some things we can say, but not a lot (we can't even conclude that the extrema exist). What kinds of things did you have in mind? Constant functions are the only examples when $A = \Bbb{R}$, not when $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I am trying to solve a "max"imization problem where the feasible set is convex but not bounded and I know the objective function over the feasible set is bounded from above. So apparently it is much harder than I expected. (and thanks for pointing that special case, I fixed it)

Comment: $x \mapsto e^{-x}$ on $[0,\infty)$ has no $\min$. This is a bounded convex function on an unbounded convex set.